# Push notification to multiple devices using rapns ( on Rails )

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

If I want to push notification to multiple devices (e.g. 1000+ devices) using rapns on Rails, could I just create one Rapns::Notification instance?

I try to assign an array included all device tokens to variable "device_token", but it always just returns nil at all. Thus I have to create as much Rapns::Notification instances as the number of the device. Is that right? Or any better way to push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that far in implementing rapns, but I guess you will have to create a new notification entry for each `device_token`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) It's true and run properly in my service.